# want to add a column dynamically by calculation the previous column jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have a pop up view where i fetch the data and put it in a table  like the image below.[image]

the are values in QTY Field .The main task is that when i edit the QTY input text for example I make this 200 then after this there will be a new column added next to that column and will hold the remaining value .for example Initial 500 ,change to 200 then the next column will show(500-200)=300 ,and it will continue as i keep changing like below image .I trying to make something like the below one.

[image]

I am using blur event but the new column is creating  at last not after the changing column and can't calculate the values.like i show in second image 
my sample code is something like below

```
 <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()"/></th>
    <th>S. No</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Tamil</th>
    <th>English</th>
    <th>Computer</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td>
    <td>1.</td>
    <td><input type='text' id='first_name' name='first_name[]'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' id='last_name' name='last_name[]'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' id='tamil' name='tamil[]'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' id='english' name='english[]'/> </td>
    <td><input type='text' id='computer' name='computer[]'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' id='total' name='total[]'/> </td>
  </tr>



</table>

<button type="button" class='delete'>- Delete</button>
<button type="button" class='addmore'>+ Add More</button>
<p>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' class='but'/></p>

 ****Javascript code**

  var i=2;
  $("#last_name").blur(function(){
  var data="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td>"+i+".  
  </td>";
  data +="<td><input type='text' id='first_name"+i+"'  
  name='first_name[]'/></td> <td><input type='text' id='last_name"+i+"' 
  name='last_name[]'/></td><td><input type='text' id='tamil"+i+"' 
  name='tamil[]'/></td><td><input type='text' id='english"+i+"' 
  name='english[]'/></td><td><input type='text' id='computer"+i+"' 
  name='computer[]'/></td><td><input type='text' id='total"+i+"' 
  name='total[]'/></td></tr>";
    $('table').append(data);
    i++;
    })
```

I Hope I make my question clear by the images help needed .Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append after row replace $('table').append(data) whith

$(data).insertAfter as demo below

```js
var i=2;
var addRow = function(){
  var data="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td>"+i+".  </td>";
  data +="<td><input type='text' name='first_name[]'/></td> <td><input type='text'  name='last_name[]'/></td><td><input type='text'  name='tamil[]'/></td><td><input type='text'  name='english[]'/></td><td><input type='text'  name='computer[]'/></td><td><input type='text'  name='total[]'/></td></tr>";
    $(data).insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'))    
    i++;
}

$(document).on('blur', 'input[name="last_name[]"]', addRow)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()"/></th>
    <th>S. No</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Tamil</th>
    <th>English</th>
    <th>Computer</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td>
    <td>1.</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='first_name[]'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='last_name[]'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='tamil[]'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='english[]'/> </td>
    <td><input type='text' name='computer[]'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='total[]'/> </td>
  </tr>



</table>

<button type="button" class='delete'>- Delete</button>
<button type="button" class='addmore'>+ Add More</button>
<p>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' class='but'/></p>
```

())

To calculate the diff you have to use the onchange event on first row to keep the original value (before change). Than on blur, when adding row, compute the difference beetwhen original saved value and actual value

Comment: thank you .But this is happening only for the first time.If i want to add again in the generated column it should work like the previous one but not working @Fabiano Taioli

Comment: Thank you very much for the help But If you don't mind can you help me on the difference calculation part ?? because I am unable to calculate it for every parent box correctly for all the boxes. I will be much grateful @Fabiano